# Wordpress will only fully load on localhost

Tags: css, wordpress, localhost, render

I have recently set up wordpress on my wamp server and when loading up the webpage through localhost it will always fully load up the entire page but when i try to access the webpage through anyother computer (even if the computer is connected to LAN ) it will only render like an HTML template, no pictures are rendered, only the box outlines,

It appears that the site is not loading up css files while online, but then i am wondering why it would work on the local host.

I have tried re installing wordpress from wordpress.org, and fully looked at the instructions and have tried to look online for some answers, but came up blank

computer information:

WAMP server
Dreamweaver

*could the problem be from dreamweaver during the site set up?

Comment: check the css path. enter the full path to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to make a localhost install work on other computers on the network you need to do a couple  things.

1. The localhost needs a dedicated address either IP or fake domain.
2. WordPress needs to be configured with that address
3. the other machines need to be told where that address is, usually in the hosts configuration file like

192.168.30.1   wp.dev

where the above is an network IP assigned to your localhost with WAMP and wp.dev is the fake dev domain. 
This pretty much needs to be set on all machines so they know where the host lives.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how to set that configuration ?

Comment: In Wordpress administration, go to **Settings**, **General**, and change both **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**.

I.E.: for me it was `http://localhost/wordpress-test`, replaced by `http://192.168.110.103/wordpress-test`.

And voilà you can preview the website through wifi on i.e. your smartphone!

Comment: Very helpful your answer, thanks ! work for me change localhost to IP address - 192.168.100.8

Answer (score 14):

I saw a question very similar to this one but for Mediawiki today. You probably have configured Wordpress with `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as your IP address, instead of your *actual* IP address.

You have to make changes in your `wp_options` table, you need to change two entries:
option id 1 - siteurl - change `http://localhost/` to `http://<your local ip>`;
option id 36 - home - change `http://localhost/` to  `http://<your local ip>`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. The only difference is that option_name "home" was option_id "2" on my database http://i.imgur.com/h0lo3a2.png

Answer (score 7):

The main issue is because WordPress uses the server addresses from the database. WordPress uses the root urls from the database options named `home` and `siteurl`, so if you try access WordPress outside that computer it may get the incorrect path for CSS and JavaScript.

If you want to get the correct path without doing a redirect, you can define a dynamic root url in `wp-config.php`

add this script below the `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`

```
/**
 * get home url from absolute path
 * @return string url to main site
 * hello@lafif.me
 */
function get_dynamic_home_url(){
    $base_dir  = ABSPATH; // Absolute path
    $doc_root  = preg_replace("!${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $base_url  = preg_replace("!^${doc_root}!", '', $base_dir);
    $protocol  = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
    $port      = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $disp_port = ($protocol == 'http' && $port == 80 || $protocol == 'https' && $port == 443) ? '' : ":$port";
    $domain    = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $home_url  = "${protocol}://${domain}${disp_port}${base_url}";

    return $home_url;
}
$url = get_dynamic_home_url();
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```

I think that would work with `http://localhost/`, `http://localhost/wp/`, `http://127.0.0.1/`, or `http://yoursite.dev/`

Comment: This worked for me. I have Ubuntu 16 LTS, wordpress 4.8.2. To clarify, the above script block is inserted after the aforementioned line but not as part of the `if` block to which `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');` is the only line to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your theme's got some incorrect paths for assets like images/stylesheets.

That would cause the sort of problem you're having, I think.   You should post the sections of your code (in your theme) that you're using to load things like images/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the general option form inside the administration page from your wordpress admin access and replace the localhost urls with the correct information.

For instance, replace `localhost` with `http://my-site.my-domain`. In case of no domain a local hostname is used inside page's code, that why you can't access from other computers. Consequently the configuration of admin page is mandatory for the web site urls after the 5min installation wordpress.