# Cannot browse WAMP from local network

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have installed **WAMP 3.0.6** with

- **Apache 2.4.23**
- PHP 7.0.10
- MySQL 5.7.14

I then installed Wordpress 4.8 in "www/wp/wp_test/"
Everything works fine and I can access the site using the address "localhost/wp/wp_test/"

Now I want to enable access to the site from other computers on the same local netword.

So I edited httpd-vhosts.conf and changed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
<Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local       
</Directory>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
<Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That didn't work, so I changed it back to default and added a new entry to point to the wordpress folder

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wordpress-test
DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/wp/wp_test"
<Directory  "d:/wamp/www/wp/wp_test/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I still cannot access the site from any other computer on the network.
Firewall is completely turned off on my computer (where WAMP is running).

P.S. : I have noticed that from my pc I can access the site using my pc's host name but when I try to use my local IP I get a 404 error returned.

Comment: Have you enter virtual host name into System HOST file as well?

Comment: Yes I have. I've tried using 127.0.0.1 and point to localhost, also tried my local IP and also tried these IPs with the "wordpress-test" that I use in the virtual host.
I can only access from my pc using either the PC's Name or "localhost" but NOT if I use the local IP of the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of twinkering I managed to make it work. 
I Used the

`WAMP Tools -> "Use a port other than 80"`

and changed the port to 8082. 
For some reason it would just not work on port 80 even thought I had nothing runing on that port (IIS stoped, Skype was closed etc).

P.S.: On a side note I had to change the wordpress url from the settings and add the PCs IP instead of "localhost" because otherwise the theme would not load on the remote PCs.
I found this from this post: 
[Wordpress will only fully load on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305999/wordpress-will-only-fully-load-on-localhost)